# How did Wynn know what happened to Meyerhold in Cube Zero?

Tags: plot-explanation, cube, cube-zero

In [Cube Zero](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0377713/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), when Wynn finally catches up to Rains, he overhears the following conversation between Haskell and Rains.

> **Rains:** Don't come near me. 
>   **Haskell:** I was protecting us. 
>   **Rains:** You murdered him. 
>   **Haskell:** He was infected, you saw it, it was spreading, we'd be dead by now. 
>   **Rains:** You don't know that.

He then says...

> Uh, actually, he's right. It's a highly contagious form of necrotizing fasciitis, flesh eating disease.

In the next scene, where Wynn is telling Rains and Haskell what he knows, he tells them

> They collect data and run tests; all kinds of tests; testing chemicals, biolical agents, measuring brain activity, endurance...

So, my question is: How did he *specifically* know that's what happened to Meyerhold (the chubby guy)? I mean how could he know it was necrotizing fasciitis if they were testing all kinds of biological agents? Is there some sort of detail that I overlooked that might explain how he knew?

- He was already inside the Cube by the time Meyerhold contracted the disease, so he couldn't have saw it on the monitor.
- He had no communication with Dodd, so Dodd couldn't have told him.
- In the shot where Rains finally gets the bottom door open to check on Meyerhold, you can see the top door is closed in the background, so he couldn't have been watching.
- It seems logical to me that the rooms are sound proof since it was high frequency sound that killed Meyerhold. So, it should be safe to assume Wynn couldn't have heard them from the other Cube.
- If the previous point is not valid, then why didn't he introduce himself sooner?

Answer (score 1):

There's two explanations for this I can think of that are supported by in-universe facts:

1. **He's seen it before**:

   The first thing we see Wynn do as part of his job is once [Ryjkin](http://moviemorgue.wikia.com/wiki/Ryjkin) dies, he removes the archive disc from their console and puts it into his file. Dodd spends this whole sequence playing chess, but Wynn doesn't: he watches every death which occurs on his watch as his opening lines indicate:

   > **Wynn**: Now that is sick. Are you watching this?
   >
   > **Dodd**: No, Thanks. I don't look any more.
   >
   > **Wynn**: We've seen a lot of... But this is just...

   And as the screen briefly shows he's given information about the cause of death:

   [image: Cube Zero: Ryjkin termination information]

   Presumably then **he's seen others die in the same way often enough to identify it**.
2. **They always do this, and Wynn knows it**:

   When Jax passes on orders to Dodd, he says (emphasis mine):

   > Order number 7 9 3-*blah blah blah blah*. Commence **standard series of needle tests** on Rains group

   After this, Dodd begins to operate some equipment at Owen's desk, a button and a viewing device, which he uses to track Jellico and activate the needle which infects her with the Necrotising Fasciitis:

   [image: Image of Dodd operating the Needle Test Machine]

   This then allows Jellico to infect Meyerhold via a scratch. As Jax said `"standard series of needle tests"` it may be (as it sounds) a standard thing to randomly infect one of them with flesh eating bacteria, Wynn could have done this to others in the past or witnessed Dodd doing it.